# Count number of occurrences in a bit column in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sql-server-2012

How to count the change in a `sql server` column like I have `Ignition` value
    Ignition
    1
    1
    0
    1
    1
    1
    0
    0
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    1
    1
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    0
    1

I want to count change only it is from 0 to 1 to make occurrence 1. It can also be from 1 to 0 for the occurrence to be 1.

Comment: You need another column indicating the order. Do you have an `id` column?

Comment: Yes i have an id column

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Simplest and shortest way for SQL server 2008 I know is:

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(partition by Ignition order by Id) as rn1,
        row_number() over(order by Id) as rn2
    from Table1
)
select count(distinct rn2 - rn1) - 1
from cte
```

Or, as @MartinSmith pointed out:

```
with cte as (
    select
        row_number() over(order by Ignition, Id) as rn1,
        row_number() over(order by Id) as rn2
    from Table1
), cte2 as (
    select distinct Ignition, rn2 - rn1
    from cte
)
select count(*) - 1
from cte2
```

for SQL Server 2012 you can use [lag()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) (or [lead()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx)) function:

```
;with cte as (
    select
        lag(Ignition) over(order by Id) as prev,
        Ignition as cur
    from Table1
)
select count(case when cur <> prev then 1 end)
from cte;
```

**<kbd>[sql fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/5c45e/3)</kbd>**

Comment: Your 2008 solution doesn't work correctly. [For this sample data](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/23533) notice that `-2` appears twice. You need to count distinct `Ignition, rn2 - rn1` pairs.

Comment: @MartinSmith you're right, thanks, I think there's more neat solution with ranks, let me check...

Comment: @MartinSmith what if I change `row_number() over(partition by Ignition order by Id) as rn1` to `row_number() over(order by Ignition, Id) as rn1`? Looks like it will work correctly this way

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1:** use the `Row_Number()` function to provide a complete (un-broken) sequence of numbers, according to our order

```
SELECT ignition
     , id
     , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) As row_num
FROM   your_table
```

**Step 4:** Make this a Common-Table Expression (CTE) so we can refer to the derived `row_num` column

```
; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ignition
       , id
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) As row_num
  FROM   your_table
)
SELECT ignition
     , id
     , row_num
FROM   cte
```

**Step 3:** join this table back to itself matching on the next/previous row

```
; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ignition
       , id
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) As row_num
  FROM   your_table
)
SELECT c1.ignition As c1_ignition
     , c2.ignition As c2_ignition
FROM   cte As c1
 LEFT
  JOIN cte As c2
    ON c2.row_num = c1.row_num + 1
```

**Step 4:** Filter the results to show those where the values aren't the same

```
; WITH cte AS (
  SELECT ignition
       , id
       , Row_Number() OVER (ORDER BY id ASC) As row_num
  FROM   your_table
)
SELECT c1.ignition As c1_ignition
     , c2.ignition As c2_ignition
FROM   cte As c1
 LEFT
  JOIN cte As c2
    ON c2.row_num = c1.row_num - 1
WHERE  c1.ignition <> c2.ignition
```

**Step 5:** ...

**Step 6:** profit!

Comment: I think this one way too complicated, for me it's easier to use apply to take previous/next in SQL 2008

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you want a solution that works in both 2008 and 2012 as you have both tags, but in 2012 (doesn't work in 2008) we did get [`LAG()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh231256.aspx) and [`LEAD()`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213125.aspx) so a `SUM()` of `[Change]` in the query below will do it for 2012. You'll have to decide how to handle the first value (which obviously doesn't have a previous value), current state it counts as a change.

```
SELECT [Id]
     , [Ignition]
     , LAG([Ignition]) OVER(ORDER BY [Id]) [Previous]
     , CASE WHEN LAG([Ignition]) OVER(ORDER BY [Id]) = [Ignition] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [Change]
  FROM [dbo].[Table]
 ORDER BY Id;
```

For 2008 a self-join should produce the same result.

```
SELECT [T1].[Id]
     , [T1].[Ignition]
     , [T2].[Ignition] [Previous]
     , CASE WHEN [T1].[Ignition] = [T2].[Ignition] THEN 0 ELSE 1 END [Change]
  FROM [dbo].[Table] [T1]
  LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Table] [T2] ON [T1].[Id] = ([T2].[Id] + 1)
 ORDER BY [T1].[Id];
```

Comment: +1 for the 2012 answer. The self-join though assumes that the ID values are without gaps.

Comment: @ypercube yeah that's true, though if they aren't it's possible to convert it to a CTE with a ROW_NUMBER() to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @t table(id int identity(1,1), ignition bit)
insert @t values(1),(0),(1),(1)
declare @Ignition varchar(max) = ''

select @Ignition = @Ignition + cast(Ignition as char(1))
from @t order by id
select @ignition

select len(replace(replace(replace(@Ignition, '10', 'x') 
       + replace(@Ignition, '01', 'x'), 1, ''), 0, ''))
```

Result:

```
2
```